# Is using custom _id in meteor risky?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I planned to create a document with an `_id` before inserting it into the DB.
I wanted to generate this `_id` using `Meteor.uuid()` (which theoretically always return a `unique id`) but I felt on this following [git issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/387)

> Thanks, good catch. The reason that this wasn't documented is that
>   we'd eventually like to **move away from string `_ids` to native binary
>   Mongo `_ids`.** Since it's used in an example though, I think we should go
>   ahead and document it and cross that bridge later. I'll do this

It seems to be a difference between a string id and a binary mongo one. Back to my question, is there a good reason I should then avoid using my custom `_id` ?

Comment: The question is: why do you need a custom _id?

Comment: I believe the "note" there in the issues was about `Meteor.uuid()` not being documented at the time. The default `_id` used by meteor was and still is a random ( but unique ) string. As the "note" says, the preference for an "alternate" was ( and still is ) the Mongo `ObjectId` format, which has it's own uniqueness. This really all comes down to "what can your client generate and handle?", if indeed it even "needs" to do such a thing or whether it can just rely on "server generated" `_id` values. But if you have something "custom", that is unique, then use it. As long as meteor has no problem

Comment: @Michelem because I always wanted to name my _id "grandma" and "daddy".
- If the generated has a duplicate the insert will not work or I might call upsert. Also I am only doing this from the server side. The reason for this is I am storing files into folders which has the name of the _id. I therefore need to create the document, watch the id, copy the file in a folder named with this id and then only flag the document as "copied". Doing this in one shot would have been better but it requires an _id first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a `Mongo.Collection` you have the option to select the way Meteor handles creating `_id` for documents which do not have and `_id` already. You can read more about it [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection).

The key point to take away is if it **does not** already have an `_id`. You are free to use whatever custom `_id` field you want. At this point this is no longer a Meteor question, but a Mongo question. Read up on the pros and cons of manually setting the `_id` field in Mongo.

Back to your question, with respect to Meteor there is no reason to avoid creating your own `_id` fields. If the custom `_id` you want to use uniquely identify's that document, then you are good to go.

And don't worry about `Meteor.uuid()`. It's no longer documented, so I'd imagine it will eventually disappear.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB [ObjectID](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) are guaranteed unique by the algorithm, so are totally conflict-safe. You could have the same safeness only actually having somewhere a sort of incremental counter shared by all your application servers and persisted, so actually reimplementing what already on you db server.

From my POV you should choose between accepting a little risk and generating a random large ID, or using MongoDB to bring them to you in advance.

With the latter I mean you could implement your custom ID generation as an empty [save](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/) on your collection, that you could later user within the actual document save: you'll pay the price of an additional database roundtrip but if your function involve moving files I'm sure it would be   negligible.

My personal advice is the latter solution.

Comment: ...of course your application should then accept (ignore) empty (_id only) documents that would be occasionally found within the collection and also from time to time clean zombies.